# Xcode 13.3 'self' refers to the method 'NewWorkoutViewController.self', which may be unexpected

Tags: swift, xcode

The `addTarget` produces warning:

[image]

Comment: Should be `lazy var` instead of `let`. I know there was a question about this a while ago and some feedback filed to Apple Developer, but I can't find it

Comment: Please post real source code, not a screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

`closeButtonTapped` means something different in a static or instance context.

When you're in a static context, as you are with a `let`, it's referring to the type method that creates instance methods when supplied with an instance. (This is not the correct way to go about using selectors.)

Switching to a `lazy var` is the correct solution because you want to refer to the instance method. You can never access instance members in property initializers that run at initialization time.